# Bounding $x_{0}$ in solutions to Diophantine equation $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} = x_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, upper-lower-bounds, vieta-jumping

Based on some computational experiments, it seems that, if $x_{0},
x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ are such that
\begin{equation*}
   \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} =
   x_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i},
\end{equation*}
then $x_{0} \le n^{2}$.

Is this bound known to be true?  And (to ask a less precise
question) whether or not this bound is true, where should one
get started to learn methods for proving bounds like this,
assuming no background beyond elementary number theory?

Comment: Very similar to http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  On this website the method is called Vieta Jumping. What Hurwitz adds is a careful inequalities for a "fundamental" solution.

Comment: what you want is to adapt Satz 6, with formula (19). Start with $n=2$ and then $n=3$   in your problem, which is a bit harder than Hurwitz. So, $(x+y+z)^2 - a xyz = 0.$  Write out  the quadratic and linear terms in $x,$   my first attempt was $x^2 + x(2y+2z-ayz) + other $  so $x'  = ayz-2y-2z-x,$ and $x' \geq x$   requires  $ayz-2x-2y-2z \geq 0.$   That is the jumping part, we can jump one variable while leaving the others alone. Then in the spirit of "infinite descent,"   a solution is fundamental when any jump increases $x+y+z$  or keeps it equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.  Thank you to [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy) for suggesting Vieta
jumping.  I had been trying Vieta jumping, but I guess I needed a
bit more encouragement to push it through.

Let $x_{0} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ be such that
\begin{equation}
   \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} =
   x_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
for some positive integers $x_{1} \le \dotsb \le x_{n}$.  Using
Vieta jumping, we may assume, without loss of generality, that
$x_{1} \le \dotsb \le x_{n} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i}$.  For,
Equation \ref{eq:1} is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
   x_{n}^{2} - \left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{i} - 2 
   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}\right) x_{n} + 
   \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}\right)^{2} = 0.
\end{equation*}
Letting $x_{n}'$ be the other root of the polynomial $t^{2} -
\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{i} - 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}\right) t +
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}\right)^{2} \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, we have
that $x_{n}x_{n}' = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}\right)^{2}$.  If
$x_{n}$ is already the smaller of these roots, then we are done.
Otherwise, we have a solution $(x_{0}, x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n-1},
x_{n}')$ to Equation \ref{eq:1} with $x_{n}' <
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i} < x_{n}$.  Reordering $x_{1}, \dotsc,
x_{n-1}, x_{n}'$ in increasing order, and then reapplying this
reduction step a finite number of times, we eventually arrive at a
solution of the desired form.

Now, given a solution $(x_{0}, x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n}) \in
\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^{n-1}$ to Equation \ref{eq:1} with $x_{1} \le
\dotsb \le x_{n} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i}$, we solve for $x_{0}$
and find that
\begin{align*}
   x_{0}
   &=%
   \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} 
   x_{i}\right)^{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}} 
   \le %
   4\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 
   x_{i}\right)^{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}} 
   \le %
   4\cdot%
   \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i}}{x_{n}}
   \cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}} \\
   &= %
   4\cdot%
   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{x_{i}}{x_{n}}
   \cdot 
   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}
   \frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{1 \le j \le 
   n-1 \\ j \ne i}} x_{j}} 
   \le %
   4\cdot
   (n-1)\cdot
   \frac{n-1}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-2} x_{j}}.
\end{align*}
Thus, if at least two of the numbers $x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n-2}$ are
$\ge 2$, or at least one of the numbers $x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n-2}$
is $\ge 4$, we have that $x_{0} \le (n-1)^{2}$, and we are done.
Otherwise, $(x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n})$ has either the form
$(1, \dotsc, 1, 1, x_{n-1}, x_{n})$ with $x_{n-1} \le
x_{n} \le n-2 + x_{n-1}$,
or the form
$(1, \dotsc, 1, 2, x_{n-1}, x_{n})$ with $2 \le x_{n-1} \le x_{n}
\le n-1 + x_{n-1}$,
or the form
$(1, \dotsc, 1, 3, x_{n-1}, x_{n})$ with $3 \le x_{n-1} \le x_{n}
\le n + x_{n-1}$.

In each of these cases, one can work out directly that $x_{0} \le
n^{2}$.  **ETA:** For example, if $(x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n})$ has the
form $(1, \dotsc, 1, 3, x_{n-1}, x_{n})$ with $3 \le x_{n-1} \le
x_{n} \le n + x_{n-1}$, then
\begin{align*}
   x_{0}
   &=%
   \frac{(n+x_{n-1}+x_{n})^{2}}{3x_{n-1}x_{n}} \\
   &=%
   \frac{n^{2}}{3x_{n-1}x_{n}} 
   +
   \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{x_{n}}\right)n 
   + 
   \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n}} + 2 + 
   \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}\right) \\
   &\le%
   \frac{n^{2}}{27} 
   +
   \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot n 
   + 
   \frac{1}{3}\left(1 + 2 + 
   \frac{n + x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}}\right) \\   
   &\le%
   \frac{n^{2}}{27} 
   +
   \frac{4}{9} n
   + 
   \frac{1}{3}\left(3 + 
   \frac{n}{3} + 1\right) \\   
   &\le%
   \frac{n^{2}}{27} 
   +
   \frac{5}{9} n
   + 
   \frac{4}{3} \\
   &\le%
   n^{2} \quad \text{for $n \ge 2$}.
\end{align*}

Thank you again to [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489714/bounding-x-0-in-solutions-to-diophantine-equation-left-sum-i-1n-x-i/4490316#comment9419413_4490316) for pointing out a missed case.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get LaTeX labels to work on MathStackExchange. The labeled equation is the first one.

Comment: I can't be sure, I don't see discussion of $(1,1,1,...,1,3, x_{n-1}, x_n )$  For $n=9,$  there are $(.....1,3,3,6) $  and $(........1,3,9,9)$  and $(....1,3,18,27) $

Comment: Will Jagy, you're right; I missed that case. However, it goes through more-or-less like the others. I edited the answer to include the computation for that case in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples to get you started;  $n=3,$  where I am printing only the fundamental solutions.

Amusing:  for fundamental with $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq .... \geq x_n \geq 1,$ apparently $x_1 \leq 5n + 10.$  Maybe provable, maybe not. The gound solution with maximal $x_1$   comes out $a=1$ and $x_1 = 5n+10,  x_2 = 4n + 8; x_3 = 5, x_4 = x_5 = x_6  = ... = x_n = 1$
Your equation becomes $100 (n+2)^2 = 100 ( n+2)^2 $

With $x \geq y \geq z \geq 1$   and $(x+y+z)^2 = a xyz,$  a fundamental solution also satisfies $ayz \geq 2(x+y+z).$  Each fundamental solution should lead to a tree  of solution triples, but this needs proof. In [Hurwitz  (1907)](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf) this is Satz 5. Meanwhile, the earliest illustration is the tree of Markov Triples, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
For $n=3.$  Just the fundamental solutions.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse 
    x:  1    y:  1    z:  1   a:   9 coprime
    x:  2    y:  1    z:  1   a:   8 coprime
    x:  3    y:  2    z:  1   a:   6 coprime
    x:  3    y:  3    z:  3   a:   3 gcd(x,y,z):  3
    x:  4    y:  2    z:  2   a:   4 gcd(x,y,z):  2
    x:  5    y:  4    z:  1   a:   5 coprime
    x:  6    y:  4    z:  2   a:   3 gcd(x,y,z):  2
    x:  8    y:  4    z:  4   a:   2 gcd(x,y,z):  4
    x:  9    y:  6    z:  3   a:   2 gcd(x,y,z):  3
    x:  9    y:  9    z:  9   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z):  9
    x: 16    y:  8    z:  8   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z):  8
    x: 18    y: 12    z:  6   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z):  6
    x: 25    y: 20    z:  5   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z):  5
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$n=4.$   Here we begin to see that   the smallest variable, here $w,$  must be very small. In Hurwitz, the Tabelle  on page 194, shows that $x_j =  1$   for $j \geq 5.$   That's an important part of how he made the table, hand calculations.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse 
    x:  1    y:  1    z:  1    w:  1   a:   16 coprime
    x:  2    y:  2    z:  1    w:  1   a:   9 coprime
    x:  2    y:  2    z:  2    w:  2   a:   4 gcd(x,y,z,w):  2
    x:  3    y:  1    z:  1    w:  1   a:   12 coprime
    x:  4    y:  2    z:  1    w:  1   a:   8 coprime
    x:  4    y:  3    z:  3    w:  2   a:   2 coprime
    x:  4    y:  4    z:  3    w:  1   a:   3 coprime
    x:  4    y:  4    z:  4    w:  4   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z,w):  4
    x:  5    y:  2    z:  2    w:  1   a:   5 coprime
    x:  6    y:  2    z:  2    w:  2   a:   3 gcd(x,y,z,w):  2
    x:  6    y:  3    z:  2    w:  1   a:   4 coprime
    x:  6    y:  4    z:  1    w:  1   a:   6 coprime
    x:  6    y:  6    z:  3    w:  3   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z,w):  3
    x:  8    y:  4    z:  2    w:  2   a:   2 gcd(x,y,z,w):  2
    x:  8    y:  5    z:  5    w:  2   a:   1 coprime
    x:  9    y:  6    z:  2    w:  1   a:   3 coprime
    x: 10    y:  5    z:  4    w:  1   a:   2 coprime
    x: 10    y:  8    z:  1    w:  1   a:   5 coprime
    x: 10    y: 10    z:  9    w:  1   a:   1 coprime
    x: 12    y:  6    z:  4    w:  2   a:   1 gcd(x,y,z,w):  2
    x: 12    y:  8    z:  3    w:  1   a:   2 coprime
    x: 15    y: 10    z:  3    w:  2   a:   1 coprime
    x: 18    y:  9    z:  8    w:  1   a:   1 coprime
    x: 21    y: 14    z:  6    w:  1   a:   1 coprime
    x: 30    y: 24    z:  5    w:  1   a:   1 coprime
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$n=5$

```
  x:  1  y:  1  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 25 coprime
  x:  2  y:  1  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 18 coprime
  x:  2  y:  2  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  a: 8 coprime
  x:  3  y:  3  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 9 coprime
  x:  3  y:  3  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  a: 2 coprime
  x:  4  y:  1  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 16 coprime
  x:  4  y:  3  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  4  y:  3  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x:  4  y:  4  z:  4  w:  2  t:  2  a: 1 gcd:  2
  x:  5  y:  2  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 10 coprime
  x:  5  y:  5  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  6  y:  2  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  a: 6 coprime
  x:  6  y:  3  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 8 coprime
  x:  7  y:  4  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 7 coprime
  x:  7  y:  7  z:  3  w:  3  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  8  y:  2  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  a: 2 gcd:  2
  x:  8  y:  4  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x:  8  y:  5  z:  5  w:  1  t:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x:  9  y:  3  z:  3  w:  2  t:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x:  9  y:  4  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  9  y:  6  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 6 coprime
  x:  9  y:  8  z:  4  w:  2  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 10  y:  5  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 11  y: 11  z:  9  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 12  y:  4  z:  4  w:  3  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 12  y:  6  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  a: 1 gcd:  2
  x: 12  y:  6  z:  4  w:  1  t:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 12  y:  8  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x: 14  y:  7  z:  4  w:  2  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 15  y: 10  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 15  y: 12  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  a: 5 coprime
  x: 16  y:  9  z:  9  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 18  y: 12  z:  3  w:  2  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 20  y: 10  z:  8  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 21  y: 12  z:  7  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 24  y: 16  z:  6  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 35  y: 28  z:  5  w:  1  t:  1  a: 1 coprime
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$n=6.  $  There is still a single fundamental solution with gcd 2. All the others have $x_6=1$

```
  x:  1  y:  1  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 36 coprime
  x:  2  y:  2  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 16 coprime
  x:  3  y:  2  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  u:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  3  y:  3  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x:  4  y:  3  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 6 coprime
  x:  4  y:  4  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 9 coprime
  x:  4  y:  4  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  u:  2  a: 1 gcd:  2
  x:  4  y:  4  z:  4  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x:  5  y:  1  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 20 coprime
  x:  5  y:  5  z:  4  w:  4  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  6  y:  2  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 12 coprime
  x:  6  y:  3  z:  3  w:  3  t:  2  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  6  y:  6  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  7  y:  2  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 7 coprime
  x:  8  y:  2  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x:  8  y:  4  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 8 coprime
  x:  8  y:  6  z:  6  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  8  y:  8  z:  3  w:  3  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  9  y:  3  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x:  9  y:  3  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x:  9  y:  8  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x:  9  y:  8  z:  4  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 10  y:  5  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 4 coprime
  x: 12  y:  4  z:  3  w:  2  t:  2  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 12  y:  6  z:  2  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 12  y:  8  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 6 coprime
  x: 12  y: 12  z:  9  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 14  y:  7  z:  2  w:  2  t:  2  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 14  y:  7  z:  4  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 15  y:  6  z:  5  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 15  y: 10  z:  2  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 3 coprime
  x: 16  y:  8  z:  4  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 18  y: 12  z:  3  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 2 coprime
  x: 18  y: 14  z:  7  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 20  y: 16  z:  1  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 5 coprime
  x: 21  y: 14  z:  3  w:  2  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 22  y: 11  z:  8  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 27  y: 18  z:  6  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
  x: 40  y: 32  z:  5  w:  1  t:  1  u:  1  a: 1 coprime
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: (1/2) Thank you for the Hurwitz paper.  Prior to posting, I'd been
trying to apply Vieta jumping to the $n=3$ case.  With your
encouragement, I tried again, and I think I have it.  However, I
had better luck picking the smaller root rather than the larger
root.  Given $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^{4}$ such that
$(a + b + c)^2 - abcd = 0$, expand as a polynomial in $c$ and
consider the constant coefficient $(a + b)^{2}$.  Vieta
jumping then lets us assume that $a \le b \le c \le a + b$.

Comment: (2/2) Then $d = \frac{(a + b + c)^{2}}{abc} \le \frac{4(a +
b)^{2}}{abc} = 4 \left(\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right) \le 8 \left(\frac{1}{a} +
\frac{1}{b}\right)$.  Thus, $d \le 8$ whenever $a \ge 2$.  The
cases where $a = 1$ can be treated separately and fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of fundamental solutions for $n=9.$  For the first time (lowest $n$), all have $ \gcd( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9) =1.$  For you, the point of the list is that the coefficient (I call it $a$ ) occurs as the $a$  value for fundamental solutions. In time, enough inequalities  may (probably will)  show that all $a \leq n^2.$  With my order $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq x_3 \geq \cdots  \geq x_9 \geq 1$  the other reasonable conjecture is that $x_1 \leq 5n+10.$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
  1   x1: 11 x2: 11 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 12 x2:  5 x3:  5 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 15 x2: 15 x3:  9 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 16 x2: 11 x3: 11 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 16 x2:  4 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 16 x2:  9 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 18 x2: 16 x3:  8 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 18 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 20 x2: 10 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 20 x2:  8 x3:  5 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 22 x2: 11 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 27 x2: 12 x3:  9 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 28 x2: 14 x3:  8 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 30 x2: 20 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 36 x2: 24 x3:  6 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 49 x2: 45 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1: 55 x2: 44 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  5 x4:  5 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1:  6 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1:  8 x2:  4 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  1   x1:  9 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  2 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
  2   x1: 10 x2:  9 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1: 15 x2:  5 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1: 18 x2:  6 x3:  6 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1: 18 x2:  9 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1: 20 x2: 10 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1: 27 x2: 18 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  2 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  2 x7:  2 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  3 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  8 x2:  6 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  8 x2:  7 x3:  7 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  2   x1:  9 x2:  4 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
  3   x1: 12 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  3   x1: 15 x2:  5 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  3   x1: 24 x2: 16 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  3   x1:  4 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  3   x1:  8 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  3   x1:  9 x2:  9 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
  4   x1: 12 x2:  3 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
  4   x1: 16 x2:  8 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
  4   x1:  4 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
  4   x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
  5   x1: 35 x2: 28 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 5 
  6   x1: 12 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
  6   x1: 21 x2: 14 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
  6   x1:  6 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
  8   x1: 14 x2:  7 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
  8   x1:  4 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
  8   x1:  9 x2:  8 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
  9   x1:  7 x2:  7 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 9 
 10   x1: 10 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 10 
 10   x1:  8 x2:  5 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 10 
 11   x1: 11 x2:  4 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 11 
 15   x1:  5 x2:  3 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 15 
 18   x1:  2 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 18 
 18   x1:  9 x2:  2 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 18 
 24   x1:  3 x2:  2 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 24 
 32   x1:  8 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 32 
 36   x1:  4 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 36 
 50   x1:  2 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 50 
 81   x1:  1 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 81
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
  S = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9
  P = x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 * x5 * x6 * x7 * x8 * x9
   S^2 = a * P
   fundamental:
   x1 >= x2 >= x3 >= x4 >= x5 >= x6 >= x7 >= x8 >= x9 >= 1  AND
   a*P >=  2*x1 * S 

 x1:  1 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 81 
 x1:  2 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 50 
 x1:  2 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 18 
 x1:  2 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  2 x7:  2 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  3 x2:  2 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 24 
 x1:  3 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  4 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 36 
 x1:  4 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
 x1:  4 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1:  4 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
 x1:  5 x2:  3 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 15 
 x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
 x1:  5 x2:  5 x3:  5 x4:  5 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1:  6 x2:  3 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
 x1:  6 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1:  7 x2:  7 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 9 
 x1:  8 x2:  1 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 32 
 x1:  8 x2:  4 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1:  8 x2:  5 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 10 
 x1:  8 x2:  6 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  8 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1:  8 x2:  7 x3:  7 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  9 x2:  2 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 18 
 x1:  9 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  2 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1:  9 x2:  4 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1:  9 x2:  8 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
 x1:  9 x2:  9 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1: 10 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 10 
 x1: 10 x2:  9 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 11 x2:  4 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 11 
 x1: 11 x2: 11 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 12 x2:  2 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1: 12 x2:  3 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
 x1: 12 x2:  4 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
 x1: 12 x2:  5 x3:  5 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 14 x2:  7 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 8 
 x1: 15 x2:  5 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 15 x2:  5 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1: 15 x2: 15 x3:  9 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 16 x2:  4 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 16 x2:  8 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 4 
 x1: 16 x2:  9 x3:  3 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 16 x2: 11 x3: 11 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 18 x2:  6 x3:  4 x4:  3 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 18 x2:  6 x3:  6 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 18 x2:  9 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 18 x2: 16 x3:  8 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 20 x2:  8 x3:  5 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 20 x2: 10 x3:  2 x4:  2 x5:  2 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 20 x2: 10 x3:  4 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 21 x2: 14 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 6 
 x1: 22 x2: 11 x3:  4 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 24 x2: 16 x3:  2 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 3 
 x1: 27 x2: 12 x3:  9 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 27 x2: 18 x3:  3 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 2 
 x1: 28 x2: 14 x3:  8 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1
 x1: 30 x2: 20 x3:  3 x4:  2 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 35 x2: 28 x3:  1 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 5 
 x1: 36 x2: 24 x3:  6 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 49 x2: 45 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1 
 x1: 55 x2: 44 x3:  5 x4:  1 x5:  1 x6:  1 x7:  1 x8:  1 x9:  1  a: 1
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$